# Apply different style for first ul with classname

Tags: css

I have following HTML structure. I want to select first ul with class name 'second class' and apply width which will be different from second ul with same class name.

```
<div>
    <div class='Link1'>
        <a>Products</a>
        <div class = 'firstClass'>
            <ul class='secondClass'>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='Link1'>
        <a>Tools</a>
        <div class = 'firstClass'>
            <ul class='secondClass'>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

I had tried below css but didnt work.

```
.Link1 > .firstClass > ul.secondClass:first-child{
    width:750px;
}
```

Comment: Can you try only `ul.secondClass:first-child { width:750px; }`, see if that works, and go from there?

Comment: @Ben I think that will select both because they are both the first child of their parents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only CSS, there is no way to stop a rule from applying after it applied on one element. This basically means

```
 .Link1 > .firstClass > ul.secondClass:first-child
```

will apply to all elements that match that selector.

However, you can easily apply a different class to only the first match using JavaScript:

```
var firstMatch = document.querySelector('.Link1 > .firstClass > ul.secondClass:first-child');
firstMatch.className = firstMatch.className + ' additionalClass';
```

... and, of course, you'd need to style the `additionalClass` in your CSS:

```
.Link1 > .firstClass > ul.secondClass.additionalClass:first-child {
  /* CSS here */
}
```

Using jQuery, it would be:

```
$('.Link1 > .firstClass > ul.secondClass:first-child').first().addClass('additionalClass');
```

---

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/0Lv1dssk/1/), as opposed to [the original, not working](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/0Lv1dssk/).

Comment: Although I havent tried Jquery solution before posting the question. Your solution works for me now. I had tried what Tony posted earlier but it wasnt working for me.